# Evaluating an integral using the gamma function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, gamma-function

My question regards an integral

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x^p)}{x^p}\mathrm{d}x$$
The answer should be $$\frac{1}{p-1}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2p})\Gamma(\frac{1}{p})$$ and I roughly know that I should apply some kind of substitution and the Cauchy theorem, but can't seem to find a way to gain this solution, I am stuck at choosing the right substitution.

Comment: Which ones did you try?

Comment: I tried rewriting the integral as $$I=\Im\{-\int_0^{\infty}x^{-p}e^{-ix^q}\mathrm{d}x\}$$ but did not find a reasonable usable substitution to finish the complex integration along the imaginary axis.

Comment: Just linking these two questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277419/show-that-int-0-infty-frac-sinxqxq-dx-frac-gamma-frac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the obvious substitution is:

$$t=x^p$$

Not thinking about the conditions for convergence for now, we have the integral:

$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x^p)}{x^p}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{p}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t^{2-1/p} }\mathrm{d}t$$

Now let's put $2-1/p=q$.

The trick is to turn this into a double integral. Notice that:

$$\int_0^{\infty} u^{q-1} e^{-tu}\mathrm{d}u=\frac{\Gamma(q)}{t^q}$$

So we have:

$$I=\frac{1}{p~ \Gamma(q)}\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty u^{q-1} \sin(t) e^{-tu}\mathrm{d}u ~\mathrm{d}t$$

Now we reverse the order of integration and take the following integral:

$$I_1=\int_0^\infty \sin(t) e^{-tu}\mathrm{d}t$$

---

This integral is easy to solve integrating by parts two times:

$$I_1=-\sin t \frac{1}{u} e^{-tu}\bigg|_0^\infty+\frac{1}{u}\int_0^\infty \cos(t) e^{-tu}\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{u}\int_0^\infty \cos(t) e^{-tu}\mathrm{d}t=$$

$$=-\frac{1}{u^2} \cos (t)~ e^{-tu} \bigg|_0^\infty-\frac{1}{u^2} \int_0^\infty \sin(t) e^{-tu}\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{u^2}(1-I_1)$$

$$\left( 1+\frac{1}{u^2}\right)I_1=\frac{1}{u^2}$$

$$I_1=\frac{1}{1+u^2}$$

---

From this our doulbe integral will turn into:

$$I=\frac{1}{p~\Gamma(q)}\int_0^\infty \frac{u^{q-1}}{1+u^2} \mathrm{d}u $$

Let's put $u^2=v$ and get:

$$I=\frac{1}{2 p~\Gamma(q)}\int_0^\infty \frac{v^{q/2-1}}{1+v} \mathrm{d}v $$

---

From one of the definitions of the Beta function:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x}dx=B(a,1-a),~~~~1>a>0$$

By the properties of the Beta function:

$$B(a,b)=\frac{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$$

$$B(a,1-a)=\frac{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(1-a)}{\Gamma(1)}=\Gamma(a) \Gamma(1-a)$$

By the reflection formula for the Gamma function:

$$\Gamma(a) \Gamma(1-a)=\frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi a)}$$

---

Here:

$$a=\frac{q}{2}=\frac{2-1/p}{2}=1-\frac{1}{2p}$$

> For $1>a>0$ we have the condition $p>\frac{1}{2}$.

$$\sin (\pi a)=\sin \left(\pi -\frac{\pi}{2p} \right)=\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2p} \right)$$

Also by the main property of Gamma function and by the reflection formula:

$$\Gamma(q)=\Gamma \left(2-\frac{1}{p} \right)=\left( 1-\frac{1}{p} \right) \Gamma \left(1-\frac{1}{p} \right)=\frac{p-1}{p}\frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi/p) \Gamma(1/p)}$$

Finally, we obtain:

$$I=\frac{1}{2 p} \frac{p} {p-1}  \frac{\sin (\pi/p) \Gamma(1/p)}{\pi} \frac{\pi}{\sin \left( \pi/(2p) \right)}$$

And the answer is indeed:

> $$I=\frac{1}{p-1}\cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2p} \right) \Gamma \left( \frac{1}{p} \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Once the integral is in the form
$$ I_p = \frac{1}{p}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{2-1/p}}\,dx \tag{1}$$
we may use the Laplace transform, giving
$$ \mathcal{L}(\sin x)=\frac{1}{1+s^2},\qquad \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x^{2-1/p}}\right)=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(2-\frac{1}{p}\right)}\,s^{1-1/p}\tag{2}$$
and
$$ I_p = \frac{1}{p\,\Gamma\left(2-\frac{1}{p}\right)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{s^{1-1/p}}{1+s^2}\,ds \tag{3}$$
is converted into an [Euler beta integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) by the substitution $\frac{1}{1+s^2}=u$.

The final outcome is a consequence of the $\Gamma$ reflection formula $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}.$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x^{p}} \over x^{p}}\,\dd x} &\
\stackrel{x^{p}\ \to\ x}{=}\
{1 \over p}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{1/p - 1}\,{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x =
{1 \over p}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{1/p - 1}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}\cos\pars{kx}\,\dd k}^{\ds{{\sin\pars{x} \over x}}}\ \,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
{1 \over p}\,\Re\int_{0}^{1}
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{1/p - 1}\expo{\ic kx}\,\dd x\,\dd k =
{1 \over p}\,\Re\int_{0}^{1}k^{-1/p}
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{1/p - 1}\expo{\ic x}\,\dd x\,\dd k =
\\[3mm] & =
{1 \over p -1}\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{1/p - 1}\expo{\ic x}\,\dd x\tag{1}
\end{align}

The '$x$-integral' is 'closed' with a quarter arc above the complex plane and the path $\braces{z = y\ic\ |\ y > 0}$. Integration along the arc vanishes out. The $x$-integration is performed by setting the branch-cut

$$
z^{1/p - 1} = \verts{z}^{1/p - 1}\exp\pars{\ic\bracks{{1 \over p} - 1}
\mathrm{arg}\pars{z}}\,,\quad
\verts{\mathrm{arg}\pars{z}} < \pi\,,\quad z \not= 0
$$.

Namely ( with the result $\pars{1}$ )
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x^{p}} \over x^{p}}\,\dd x} & =
{1 \over p - 1}\,\Re\bracks{-\int_{\infty}^{0}y^{1/p - 1}
\exp\pars{\ic\,{\pi \over 2}\bracks{{1 \over p} - 1}}\expo{-y}\,\ic\dd y}
\\[3mm] & =
{1 \over p - 1}\,\Re\pars{\exp\pars{{\pi \over 2p}\,\ic}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}y^{1/p - 1}\expo{-y}\,\dd y
\\[3mm] & =
\color{#f00}{{1 \over p - 1}\,\cos\pars{{\pi \over 2p}}\Gamma\pars{{1 \over p}}}
\end{align}

Comment: I like this answer the best, but I don't understand how we choose the branch-cut

Comment: @YuriyS Once we return across the path $\left\lbrace z = y\mathrm{i}\ |\ 0 < y < 1\right\rbrace$ we are 'visiting' the complex plane. In such situation, we have to choose a branch-cut for $z^\left(1/p - 1\right)$ because it's multivalued.  In particular, the chosen branch-cut leads to $z = y\exp\left(\pi\mathrm{i}/2\right)$ for $y > 0$ in the above mentioned path.